# Determine image name from dynamically created URL

Tags: java, html, image, liferay

I'm using Liferay 6.1. My problem is that when I create a url using Liferay tags the browser does not seem to be able to determine the filename correctly. For example using the below url in the `<img>` tag `src` attribute results in the image being named "images" and when the file is saved the new file's name is images.jpg instead of imageId123.jpg

http://example.com/images?p_p_id=imagesdisplay_WAR_imagesportlet&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&_imagesdisplay_WAR_imagesportlet_struts.portlet.action=%2Fview%2FgetWmarkedImage&imageId=imageId123

I need the image name to be imageId123 so when it's saved it will have a file name such as imageId123.jpg. Is there a way to specify the image name or the downloaded file name when the image is saved on the computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall not do it via the download-filename.

Use `content-disposition` header instead.

```
responseFile.setContentType("application/x-download");
responseFile.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=imageId123");
```